# How to add image caption on Google code wiki

Tags: image, wiki, caption

I am using Google code wiki page for documentation. The way I adding image into my article is inserting a link to the image, for example put this link into where I want to place the image.

http://code.google.com/images/code_sm.png

The question is I want to add caption under the picture and also want to edit the size of this picture. How can I do that? I didn't find the Syntax on their support page:

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WikiSyntax

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to solve it. Google code wiki page supports html. so the size of picture can be edited using tag "img" and attributes "title" "width" and "height" .

```
 
img title="Map of 2nd floor" src="http://kth-hvac.googlecode.com/..." width="700px" height="300px"
```

Link is
http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WikiSyntax#HTML_support